# Looking for intuition regarding continuity and vector-valued functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a vector-valued function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of a single real variable, $t$,

$$f(t) = \langle t,t\rangle$$

Now, this function is continuous in $t$.  However, if I understand it, a vector can be moved around the plane so long as its components remain the same.  For instance, the points $p_1 = (1,1)$, $p_2 = (2,2)$ and $p_3 = (3,3)$ can be used to form the vectors $p_2 - p_1 = \langle 1,1 \rangle$ and $p_3 - p_2 = \langle 1,1 \rangle$, and these two vectors are equivalent despite being made up of different sets of points.

As a result, if I were to choose to draw these vectors in the plane, I could do so such that no two vectors share a common tail or head.  In effect the graph of this function in the plane can be made to either trace out a continous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or could be made to reduce to a disconnected set of points there.

I'm trying to better understand the intuition of this.  The function is continuous in the vector space, right?  But it isn't continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ necessarily.  What does that mean?  For instance, why isn't $\mathbb{R}^2$ the vector space, and how does it differ?  What does it mean when I choose to trace out a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with my function?  Is it "doubly continuous" or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "moving of the vector" refers to a changing "base point" for the vector.  To move the vector in a continuous way you are referring to means to move to base point in a continuous way.  Therefore, the range you want is not $\mathbb{R}^2$, but instead $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$, to specify the location of both the base point and the vector.  Then you can give a continuous function for the base point as well.

Comment: So then is it true that if I chose the range to only be $\mathbb{R}^2$ I am forcing the base point to remain constant? Or is it that the the original function simply maps to the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ while the function *along with its graph* maps to both the vector space and the real plane?

Comment: Also (sorry for all the questions :-P ) what does the notation for that look like?  since $f(t)$ was originally defined to produce a vector, and since I now want to also produce a point, would I write it as something like $f(t) = ( \langle t,t \rangle (t,t))$ if, say, I wanted to map each vector to its components reckoned from the origin?  That seems somewhat clumsy to me but it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: Yes, if the range is only $\mathbb{R}^2$ the base point is assumed to be the origin, and so the base point does not move.  To your second question, your base point is moving with t.  To keep it fixed at the origin, I would write $(0,0) \times <t,t>$.